# Multiple shop fronts withing drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

bit stuck at the moment and searching for an answer is not really paying off.

I am making a new site in drupal. What I basically want to do is...

An end user can come along, set up a shop and add multiple products. 
therefor resulting in a site that has multiple shops that are managed by the user themselves.

Is this possible in Drupal?

any ideas or references to point me in the right direction ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Drupal can do what you have stated. All you need to do is add functionality to it example http://drupal.org/project/commerce

This will allow you to acheive 90% of what you want.

I would suggest you buy a book on drupal and read through that book first. If you don't know what modules are and are fresh  of the boat.

The learning curve is not very steep. If you are a programmer then its going to be fun for you but if you are not then its best just to hire someone.

Let me know if you need more help.
vishal

Comment: Thanks vishal for your reply. I guess what I am wanting to do is to enable a user to sign up to my site and then ultimately, create a subsite where they can manage there own products etc within that sub site . ie/ www.example.com (main site) then user will have username.example.com. I htink this will be the best way to do it. can you point me in the right direction or the modules required to do this.

Comment: if you make a username.example.com then you will need drush , commerce to do this for you. There will be more modules which you will need but I have stated the major ones .